# Backpropagation - Cáclulo dos Deltas

Tags: c++

Galera, estou com dúvida de como calcular o erro para a camada intermediária. Estou usando esse pdf http://www.dct.ufms.br/~mzanusso/IACC-02/Backprom.pdf. Na pagina 5 ele começa a calcular o erro dos deltas da camada intermediária, estou com duvida de onde saem esses valores marcados em vermelhos nesse link > http://prntscr.com/97d7ks. Espera ajuda. Abraços

Segue o código: http://pastebin.com/5Ss84nzt

Comment: Por favor, inclua o código e screenshot aqui na pergunta.

Comment: O código é esse > http://pastebin.com/JF7CfNs7. A minha dúvida é realmente como encontrar esses valores que estao circulados em vemelho no print http://prntscr.com/97d7ks, que seria o Wkj, nao sei como encontrar esses valores

Comment: Ok, eu devia ter sido mais explicito. Por favor, confira este post da nossa área Meta [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/201) (não pode) e a central de ajuda: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **É só [edit]** a pergunta e acrescentar esses detalhes.